# How do you validate a laravel json object request in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

How to validate a laravel request object, I have this conditions

```js
request()->validate([
                'avatar' => 'required|image',
                'display_name' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
                'role_id'      => 'required|integer',
                'username' => 'required|unique:users|min:4|max:15',
                'email'        => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'phone_number' => 'required|min:3',
                'password'     => 'required|min:6',
                'country_id' => 'required|integer'
]);
```

But in my request it was stored in an object form, what should I do to make the validations work ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You validate it the same way you validate a multi-dimensional array:

```
request()->validate([
    'form.avatar' => 'required|image',
    'form.display_name' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
    'form.role_id'      => 'required|integer',
    'form.username' => 'required|unique:users|min:4|max:15',
    'form.email'        => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'form.phone_number' => 'required|min:3',
    'form.password'     => 'required|min:6',
    'form.country_id' => 'required|integer'
]);
```

If your form is an array of object, you can use wildcard

```
request()->validate([
    'form.*.avatar' => 'required|image',
    'form.*.display_name' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
    'form.*.role_id'      => 'required|integer',
    'form.*.username' => 'required|unique:users|min:4|max:15',
    'form.*.email'        => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'form.*.phone_number' => 'required|min:3',
    'form.*.password'     => 'required|min:6',
    'form.*.country_id' => 'required|integer'
]);
```

Comment: Hey, I'm on laravel 5.5

Comment: Nested attribute validation is valid from Laravel 5.2 so you should be fine https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: But I get this sir :) `message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'form.username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `form`.`username` = chandler40)"
`

Answer (score 1):

For unique validation you can pass the field name on which you need to apply validation, by default it takes the key name.

You can use this for unique validation on object data:-

```
'form.username' => 'required|unique:users,username|min:4|max:15'
```